# ItemRenderer shows through ItemEditor on AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, mxml, advanceddatagrid

I'm pretty new to Flex, so there's probably a good chance I'm missing something obvious, but in the first example code, everything works as expected. When not editing the cell, it shows a centered date as plain text. When editing, it shows a DateField editor. The second example is exactly the same as far as I can tell, other than the fact that it is an `AdvancedDataGridColumn`. Using that code with an `AdvancedDataGrid`, when I go into edit mode I can see the text from the normal item renderer behind the `DateField` editor (between the text input and calendar icon). Did I do something wrong here? How can I hide that? Thanks in advance.

Example 1:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn id="endColumn"
                   dataField="endDate"
                   headerText="End"
                   editorDataField="selectedDate"
                   editable="true"
                   labelFunction="{this.formatDate}"
                   width="80"
                   textAlign="center" >
    <mx:itemEditor>
        <fx:Component>
            <mx:DateField yearNavigationEnabled="true" formatString="DD/MM/YY" />
        </fx:Component>
    </mx:itemEditor>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Example 2:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="endColumn"
                           dataField="endDate"
                           headerText="End"
                           editorDataField="selectedDate"
                           editable="true"
                           labelFunction="{this.formatDate}"
                           width="80"
                           textAlign="center" >
    <mx:itemEditor>
        <fx:Component>
            <mx:DateField yearNavigationEnabled="true" formatString="DD/MM/YY" />
        </fx:Component>
    </mx:itemEditor>
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
```

Comment: any chance you could post some ready to run code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space between the dateInput and the icon is normally transparent. I'm not sure why `mx:DataGrid` hides the rendered text and the `mx:AdvancedDataGrid` doesn't.

Anyway, there's an easy solution to your problem. Just paint the itemEditors background in the color you like. The following should work.

```
<mx:itemEditor>
    <fx:Component>
        <mx:DateField yearNavigationEnabled="true" formatString="DD/MM/YY">
            <fx:Script>
                <![CDATA[
                    protected override function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
                    {
                        graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF); // white
                        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
                        graphics.endFill();

                        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
                    }
                ]]>
            </fx:Script>
        </mx:DateField>
    </fx:Component>
</mx:itemEditor>
```